# how to connect mysql from c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I downloaded `mysql.dll`. When I add this to my solution, I get an error like

> Please make sure that file is accesssble and that it is a valid assembly or com component...

Please tell me how to connect to MySql from C# and any problems I may encounter while using MySql in C#. Will it run on every system?

Comment: What is the version of Visual Studio and MySql?

Comment: You can try data provider for MySQL from Devart: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/ . Free edition inludes basic connectivity features.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

You can download MySql connector and use it

Answer (score 1):

you should reference MySql.Data.dll, not mysql.dll

To open database connection, you can use something like this

```
        internal static MySqlConnection GetConnection(string dbserver, string username, string password, string databasename)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=" + dbserver + ";User Id=" + username + ";Password=" + password + ";Persist Security Info=True;database=" + databasename);
            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Code to handle exception
        }
    }
```

About supported platforms, the documentation says:

> Connector/NET runs on any platform that supports the .NET framework.
>   The .NET framework is primarily supported on recent versions of
>   Microsoft Windows, and is supported on Linux through the Open Source
>   Mono framework

Answer (score 0):

First you have to Add MySQL.data.dll into References

Second, here is example code to connect to MySQL server and select a simple data from server

> ```
>     private string _server;
>
>     private string _port;
>
>     private string _database;
>
>     private string _uid;
>
>     private string _pwd;
>
>     //Constructor
>     public MySQL()
>     {
>         Initialize();
>     }
>
>     //Initialize connection string
>     private void Initialize()
>     {
>         _server = "10.11.12.13";
>         _database = "ABCDEF";
>         _port = "3306";
>         _uid = "root";
>         _pwd = "raat";
>         var connectionString = "SERVER=" + _server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + 
>                                   _database + ";" + "PORT=" + _port + ";" + "UID=" + _uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + _pwd + ";";> 
>         
>         connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
>     }
>
>     //Connect to server
>     private bool OpenConnection()
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
>                 connection.Open();
>
>             return true;
>         }
>         catch (MySqlException ex)
>         {
>             //When handling errors, you can your application's response based 
>             //on the error number.
>             //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
>             //0: Cannot connect to server.
>             //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
>             switch (ex.Number)
>             {
>                 case 0:
>                     Global._logger.Info("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
>                     break;
>
>                 case 1045:
>                     Global._logger.Info("Invalid username/password, please try again");
>                     break;
>             }
>             Global._logger.Info(ex.Message + " / " + ex.StackTrace);
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
>
>     //Close connection
>     private bool CloseConnection()
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
>                 connection.Close();
>
>             return true;
>         }
>         catch (MySqlException e)
>         {
>             Global._logger.Info(e.Message + " / " + e.StackTrace);
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
>
>     //Create query to select data from Server
>     public string GetStudentName(string studentId)
>     {
>         var query = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE StudentID = '" + studentId;
>
>         if (OpenConnection())
>         {
>             //Create command
>             var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
>
>             //Create data reader and excute datareader
>             MySqlDataReader dataReader = null;> 
>
>             try
>             {
>                 dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
>             }
>             catch (MySqlException mySQLEx)
>             {
>                 Global._logger.Error(mySQLEx);
>             }
>
>             string studentName = "";
>
>             try
>             {
>                 if (dataReader != null)
>                 {                         
>                     while (dataReader.Read())
>                     {                      
>
>                         studentName= Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Name"].ToString());
>
>                     }
>                     
>                     dataReader.Close();
>                     
>                     CloseConnection();    
>
>                     return studentName;                    
>                 }               
>
>             }
>             catch (Exception e)
>             {
>                 Global._logger.Info(e.Message + e.Source);>              
>             }
>         }          
>     }
> ```